# How to find the best settings for Cyclic voltametery test?

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement, duty-cycle

I am trying to conduct a CV TEST (Cyclic Voltammetry). However, I am unable to get the current peaks on my plot. I tried different ranges of Voltage at different scan rates. However, I could not achieve any meaningful full result. can the test be successful if it is still not showing the current peaks?

The material I am testing right now is Agar (culture gel).

My plots look like:

[image]

I am scanning at 100mV/s and starting a potential of -0.1.

is there a way for me to find the correct range to locate my peaks or is it normal for some material not show them

Comment: have you tried using the "screenshot" function of your operating system instead of literally taking a photo? it comes out way better, I promise!

Comment: Also, can you elaborate why you think this result isn't meaningful? Looks pretty significant to me!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I thought the whole point of a CV test is to locate (potential points "peaks"). I can not locate them from the plot. so I not sure how to find my anodic and cathodic potential points. ?

Comment: Are you trying to get something like [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/147578/79678) classic shape? If so, what is the electroactive species in agar? Maybe you are just getting background.

Comment: It's not the "whole point", no.

Comment: @EdV yes, I am trying to. it is nothing but agar for now. I want to make sure my test is correct before adding the electroactive species.

Comment: I think you are just seeing background right now, so perhaps try potassium ferricyanide: it it the standard test substance. Best of success!

Comment: What are you using for a voltage sweep gen. 0 Ohms or 50 Ohms?  Looks like 10 Ohms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about Agar or volummetry but higher scan rates ought to increase current dues the dielectric constant and how thin the material layer is without voids between conducting electrodes.

This is essentially a voltage sensitive material with polar hysteresis created by a REDOX cell voltage reaction, much like permeability is to magnetic materials which normally display H field current on the X axis orthogonal to yours.

My suggestion is to change the thickness and

- also change the sweep waveform to more of a square wave with slew rate limits.( if this is permitted) If this makes it worse then you are seeing excessive ESR from galvanic resistance.

  - in event of the above failure, then I would suggest investigating your electrode material for better types. ( gold plated)

Ic = C dV/dt for linear dielectrics and hysteresis depends on saturation of the polar ions without voids or contaminants.

I’ll have to read up on  electrochemical impedance spectroscopy. Right now it looks a bit like a 10 Ohm resistor with asymmetric hysteresis.

[Here is my simulation of your signals using a buffered bipolar Howland Current Source](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0ZgjCBmAHJAbATlQFmwVi7AExbqyxYi5KWUS4CmAtGQFACGIhuqIsqECVNT4RhuEM3GwYMiIzCRBuBAiJVcAdm5ViEhUoRZiGwhvJJ0hdL1lgWAdxBYkEWBp7PXWCncdYEhLzuTgG8luAsAE6c3Jy6gtSEunRRMTwuiEIgGa4yqVzpXhQ5NnnRCGAUAQKCiIQQrg5pQTwFcT4sAEqcYIm69cLBAlBgKrzgEwq4LADmvN7ZRbyE1A1NbRlt5B2ObUkUeya8qRUHSNQJnOcT0k2nVxeVnEd2c-6B9%20%20ItWu7saYfJ4AiIAD14SA0lHghDclAoBwonVgLDBFTo8BUdHhnERhBRnAqYUS-B68ARIE6CHxAXE9UhCFwtOkThxFKw1MwMQQUIOsXJABsAPZsAAmAB0AM4S%20wASwALgBjAAWLDliCQFDIgS%20WpuElgCGgzg0qio6EwK1q8jQOCQqBMYEZVlQRG50ggIvoADM2ABXfly1XqzUknUkuTwaSQdC4IhCAgwBBmbB6G1Ce31J2YV2lECen3%20wOOS77JybZJNHULHUrCJ%20ULbMtLXzB3hEVsiCLdL6cnAUTkNJyuQKDqZdEKBWDhPthEcTLARucNSDTcpZTvIEOD912NeJI73YG5FuXDKeRZ1pvzeEZHL5f79XrtG4sADKE8QT0u90HPv5EvoCZpgXblNA8agNCeXVXAAfQKGCwBgkQYEIJDoGUTBcFIZB3H8F0EOgGBYAQuCkJgqliy-KizlWFgFUyR4qmoyZIHgBQiNsGQrG4TBrHYuA6IYuoah4aoWLYwid1sWMqEgjRIX45F6KnQIVmEcIxOXXoYEsTjZHga0sG4F0tAsF1kDADQFkUu4v3qT8mI6CUrzccCIFLX82H-egWAAB2aYFXOeSdJj8lyFm4JYyQiAA3ZoxL2a5BwXKAeFHFcWDi0s1OfTT52XNKWOmQwQC9ewRUiQVfLFABHVxeEgMx-FwFYVKQHdCCYBSRlkGFUBhAaWvkzEStyFgRXi%20y2gZVTSvKyrqrq8bcpa3Kprmiqqtq3d4tW6aNQmDR8niPb4gOlJdn6a5Etov5Wmu-4XnWM7eVE871liTcHNbE8vwO%204ZsvAHam-H5bKqVbgbS1IVMQVbYby6ZHFhnLsqSpoEYO0svpbFHrk7HLcY0g6N3ekC4U1dstA%20VbXGI7ASOQhnYGgLQSA1F0IXQXoiCYIgNDQvShYQPmAjI1CyHIjGNNOiGRw%20%207Emu9H6NR5WLns5cuFTKgyDIfrufNJBuRsu64dU65AZ2nLAZtzXKBYQUQEhNpXH4FCoBjdqMHNdnYHwCwergCZAnpR222aLxBFhfjg-Y9AjJcXpCGwcgNHNPjOAjqlkGyRARjGeAADFInoGrfXoAA7BUAE8WFz1ZxnbABZNgQUlAA1QUAzYGYfNzhBM9jsAM9HsfR-GABhNhfLYBV5TYaufKAA) with a variable sweep current linear slow sweep (faster than real-time) of your signal with ideal diodes and 0.6V bipolar cells with an RC network.

Comment: On second thought, wouldn’t the REDOX cell voltage charge up better by using a constant current source or slow triangular current source rather than a triangular voltage source?  Much like charging a polar miniature coin cell battery.? But I suspect the thickness will only affect the capacitance and not the cell voltage EIS. And the electrode material will affect the ESR greatly.